If the data records were accidentally deleted, what should I do?
i am studing wagtails, If the data records were accidentally deleted, what should I do?  D:\conda_env\chucansvn\lib\site-packages\wagtail\query.py:565: RuntimeWarning: Specific versions of the following items could not be found. This is most likely because a database migration has removed the relevant table or record since the item was created:
[{'id': 9, 'title': 'blog_index_page', 'type': <ContentType: blog | blog index page>}, {'id': 7, 'title': 'Our Blog', 'type': <ContentType: blog | blog index page>}, {'id':
8, 'title': 'blogtitle', 'type': <ContentType: blog | blog index page>}]
Is there a graceful way to solve this problem?
